# Cacheing e-tags viewing

Tags: xml, caching, etag

I am new to XML and caching and one of the comments is:

All catalogue methods will now return an ETag header, like this:
ETag: “686897696a7c876b7e”  - should I be able to view this in the JSON Feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. They're part of the HTTP response headers. The JSON data would be considered part of the response body.

Comment: Thanks Chris,  are you able to provide me an example so I can get a better grasp